# ACPI : EC: Fail in evaluating the _REG object of EC device. Broken bios is suspected

Tags: boot, kernel, bios, acpi, msi

I can't install linux with kernel over than 4.x on my computer. (MSI GP72-6QE-087XFR Leopard Pro)

Tried : Ubuntu 15.10, debian 8 and linux mint 17.3.

This is saying:
"ACPI : EC: Fail in evaluating the _REG object of EC device. Broken bios is suspected."

Looks like a bios problem for me, and i did buy my computer without OS so i only have linux choice.
I can install Ubuntu 14.10 but the wifi is not supported (iwlwifi 3165). As soon as i update the kernel or the operating system (to ubuntu 15.04 for example), the computer is unusable (it only shows the error message and won't boot).

What can i do?

Comment: The Embedded Controller driver evaluates the _REG ACPI object to determine the operation region of the Embedded Controller.  For some reason, this failed (perhaps the EC _REG object was not defined in your firmware).  As it stands, the kernel driver ignores this issue, flags it up as a problem with the firmware and then continues to initialise the Embedded Controller anyway.    I suspect there may be other issues which are the root cause of your issues and I don't think this is the root issue to your problem.

Comment: It could prove more useful if you can show the entire kernel log rather than this one line.

Comment: I will reinstall linux (14.10) which boot  dump you the log. <del>is /var/log/syslog is ok?</del>

edit: will dump the /var/log/kern.log instead :)

Comment: yes,  hopefully we can deduce what's going on from that

Comment: Hope it will help : http://paste.ubuntu.com/14091707/

Comment: I have the same problem with a pendrive boot on my new laptop. Hard to read syslog then. Any clue on how to retrieve relevant boot info?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just starting the PC with the boot parameters

```
nomodeset idle=nomwait
```

For ASUS Rog 6th generation intel just

```
idle=nomwait
```

is enough.

Thanks myself.