# new laptop ubuntu installation problem

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, uefi, live-cd

I'm really  a GNU/Linux newbie and tried to install *ubuntu 15.04, 15.10 and even 16.04* on my new laptop with  *i5 6300hq gtx970m* and windows installed with UEFI.

Everytime I try to install  ubuntu, I get the following error:

```
"ACPI : EC: Fail in evaluating the _REG object of EC device. Broken bios is suspected."
```

What's annoying is that I can't even run any live CD of ubuntu  or install any on vmware. 
Any help please?

Comment: This might help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/709961/acpi-ec-fail-in-evaluating-the-reg-object-of-ec-device-broken-bios-is-suspe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your acpi is complaining for some reason and the only workaround for this is to disable acpi on your system during the installation.

There are 2 ways to workaround this issue:

you can either set boot parameter to nomodeset (here are the steps/details):

[ACPI : EC: Fail in evaluating the _REG object of EC device. Broken bios is suspected](https://askubuntu.com/questions/709961/acpi-ec-fail-in-evaluating-the-reg-object-of-ec-device-broken-bios-is-suspe)

Or set boot parameter to acpi=off

If you don't know how to set boot parameter follow the step by step guide of official ubuntu here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions

This is probably due to driver incompatibility for acpi (newer), once you hace the system up and running without acpi you can find the correct drivers and update them.

Comment: Whilst these links may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the links for reference.

Comment: So, I managed to boot with live disk of 16.04 (didn't try 15.10) and I was wondering if I should install this alpha or go for the 15.10, considering I won't be using it  heavily nor relying on it for serious work but keeping it up to date till the official release. It's just that I'd like to have the less things that should not be in the LTS version (as python2 and some other "junks").Any advice?
Sorry for my english by the way, it's not my native tongue.

Comment: So, I managed to boot with live disk of 16.04 (didn't try 15.10) and I was wondering if I should install this alpha or go for the 15.10, considering I won't be using it  heavily nor relying on it for serious work but keeping it up to date till the official release. It's just that I'd like to have the less things that should not be in the LTS version (as python2 and some other "junks").Any advice?
Sorry for my english by the way, it's not my native tongue.

Comment: So, I managed to boot with live disk of 16.04 (didn't try 15.10) and I was wondering if I should install this alpha or go for the 15.10, considering I won't be using it  heavily nor relying on it for serious work but keeping it up to date till the official release. It's just that I'd like to have the less things that should not be in the LTS version (as python2 and some other "junks").Any advice?
Sorry for my english by the way, it's not my native tongue.