# Install Ubuntu MSI GP72. ACPI : EC: Fail in evaluating the _REG object of EC device. Broken bios is suspected

Tags: dual-boot, mate, nomodeset, msi

I want to install the ubuntu mate 16.04, I tried the ubuntu 15.10 and 14.04 and no one work, always it is showing

> [ACPI : EC: Fail in evaluating the _REG object of EC device. Broken bios is suspected].

I can't install linux on my computer (MSI GP72-6QE-087XFR Leopard Pro).

Someone gave this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/q/709961):

> Just start the PC with the boot option
>
> ```
> nomodeset idle=nomwait
> ```
>
> For asus Rog 6th generation intel just
>
> ```
> idle=nomwait
> ```

But I don't know where is the boot option, I want to install ubuntu mate 16.04 or ubuntu 15.10.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with Ubuntu (16.04 & 14.04) on a "MSI GP62 Leopard Pro"

I made it to boot correctly by adding at the end of the boot line (after "quiet splash") :

> nomodeset acpi_osi=

(you can access the command line by typing "e" when you see the grub ("Try Ubuntu" / "Install Ubuntu" / ...)

[more information here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132)

Comment: Does not work on MS-16J5 when booting Ubuntu 14.04 from DVD.

Answer (score 0):

In the options (try Ubuntu, install ...etc)
Press E ....
You will be in an editor, put the string you need in the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Tested on: notebook model MSI GP72-6qe

Writing `acpi=off` on grub options, with this Ubuntu booted correctly, then apply all updates, in "privete controller" or "controladores privativos" (in spanish) choose Processor microcode firmware for intel . . . and reboot.

Now ubuntu run OK! with hot keys, acpi options, wifi, bluetooth, etc.